# SQL - average distance per day

Tags: sql

I have a problem here: "Show average distance per day driven by cars from Paris"

I have also 2 tables referred to this problem

1. `table_cars`: `id`, `brand`, `type`, `license`
2. `table_distances`: `id_car`, `date`, `distance`

I have managed to select "the average distance for the cars from Paris"

```
 select avg(table_distances.distance)
     from table_distances
     INNER JOIN table_cars ON table_distances.id_car = table_cars.id
     where table_cars.license = 'Paris';'
```

Though, I have still a problem with average distance per day. I looked over related questions on the stackoverflow/google but I got more confused.

Can somebody explain how I can improve my query to show average distance per day?

Comment: You're looking for a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What data does the table contain on days?

Comment: Sounds like a class question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the distances per car per date.

```
SELECT id_car, date, AVG(table_distances.distance) 
FROM table_distances
INNER JOIN table_cars 
ON table_distances.id_car = table_cars.id
WHERE table_cars.license = 'Paris'
GROUP BY id_car, date
ORDER BY id_car, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the date to what you select and group by it so it's averaged per row:

```
SELECT table_distances.date, avg(table_distances.distance)
FROM table_distances
  INNER JOIN table_cars ON table_distances.id_car = table_cars.id
WHERE table_cars.license = 'Paris'
GROUP BY table_distances.date
```

Comment: Lol, it was so easy. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `GROUP BY` clause to your DATE column

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) for SQL GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT AVG(td.distance)
     FROM table_distances td
     INNER JOIN table_cars tc ON td.id_car = tc.id
     WHERE tc.license = 'Paris'
     GROUP BY td.date;
```

Then you have to get average distance of a car per day